# Odd Behaviour of Icon Caching

Tags: django, http, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

Consider this `view` that generates an `ico` image:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.somewhere import Favicon

# View URL: `/<str:colour>.ico`
def favicon( request, colour ):
    response = HttpResponse(
        Favicon.render( colour ),
        status=200
    )

    response['Content-Type'] = 'image/x-icon'
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=31536000'

    return response
```

*`Favicon.render()` returns a valid byte stream, do not pay any attention on that.*

Here is a `link` element in `head` of my HTML document:

```html
<link rel=icon href=/7f9fa4.ico>
```

Now comes the question: why each time I reload the page, my browser, *Chromium 73*, makes a request to `/7f9fa4.ico`, instead of retrieving the icon from cache? If I will open `/7f9fa4.ico` in a new tab, first time request to the server would be sent, further my browser will retrieve an image from cache; now tell me what's wrong with the browser-caching system.

---

Here is a request *(cookies and preferences are omitted)*:

```
GET /7f9fa4.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
```

And these are response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 07:03:58 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.8
Content-Type: image/x-icon
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 196
```

Console output (if it somehow could help):

```
[05/Jun/2019 09:17:42] "GET /7f9fa4.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 196
```

---

Also, if I will remove `link` element from `head`, browser will make requests to `/favicon.ico` (which in my case just mirrors `/ffffff.ico`) each time I reload the page with the same effect.

Comment: pls try to manually specify into html this tag `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/7f9fa4.ico" />` and write a result.

Comment: @SergeyMiletskiy no offense, but if the solution was so simple, I would have done it myself. I've tried it -- no results.

Comment: nothing personal, it is just a development process. :)  My next idea - you are running your server in the DEBUG mode, so the static serving differs. Try to set DEBUG=False

Comment: @SergeyMiletskiy still no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you may find is that this request is being made to validate the cached content.  I noticed that the request you sent to the server has `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cacheability

> **no-cache**
>   Forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy.

So it forces caches to submit the request for validation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma#Directives

> **no-cache**
>   Same as Cache-Control: no-cache. Forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for validation before releasing a cached copy.

These state that the browser would be expected to send a request to your server for "validation" before it uses the cache icon.